# How to pass model to conditional partialview having separate model for each view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am binding one partial view (among 3 views) to the main view.
Main view having model tightly bind with it.
Which partial view is going bind is decided at get method of controller according to the conditions.
Either it bind one of three view or bind none.
From controller I am returning main view with it's model & a string having partial view path.
If string has value i.e. path of partial view then it binds that view.

```
@if (strPartialPage != null && strPartialPage != "")
     {
         @Html.Partial(strPartialPage)
     }
```

Every partial view has separate models tightly bind with that view.

How do I pass model to the partial view.

Comment: I want to pass model according to the PartialView bind without using ViewBag. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(model.Partialviewmodel!=null)
{
 @Html.Partial("_PartialviewName",model.Partialviewmodel)
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: ohk i remember this thing always

Comment: In my case partial view is not fixed. It is decided according to some conditions on Get action of controller. Every view has it's own model. So model is also finalized after finalizing partial view. So I've checked "strPartialPage" string variable for PartialView path. Currently I'm handing 3 partial views. It may increase. So I can't give any hard-coded view or any conditional statement (like if...else..). Is there any way?